# Angular generator without Ruby

Tags: ruby, angularjs, sass, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

The [angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) has a dependency on [compass](https://rubygems.org/gems/compass) and thus [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) when using SASS.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible/practical to remove the ruby dependency by using something like [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass)?
2. If so, how do I accomplish #1 and still use angular generator to generate controllers, routes, services, etc in the future?

Comment: Honestly, I am stuck with this problem too. Installing project dependencies, including Ruby for just one thing (compass server, really), is a huge pain in the butt. Answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Yeoman Angular generator and you wish to use SASS/SCSS without depending on Ruby, you could use the [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) Grunt module.

Yeoman is essentially a project set-up with Grunt so you can just add whichever Grunt modules you need. If you are unfamiliar with Grunt, you can read the documentation [here](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started).

Essentially, you can set up the Grunt configuration for your SASS task, then register the task in your generated project's `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                'main.css': 'main.scss'
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
```

You should note that this Grunt module uses [Node SASS](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) for CSS compilation instead of Compass, so you may be missing out on some Compass mixins you may be used to.